# Referring to a CSS Module within a ternary operator

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript

Given the div structure

```
<div className={
   `${style.cell} 
      ${cell === Player.Black ? "black" : cell === Player.White ? "white" : ""}`}key={colIndex}/>
```

And the related CSS

```
.cell {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: burlywood;
  cursor: pointer;
}
  
.black {
  background-color: #000;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
  
.white {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
```

How can I refer to the `.cell.black` and `.cell.white` class within the conditional using `style...` similar to how I would if `className` was

```
{`cell ${cell === Player.Black ? "black" : cell === Player.White ? "white" : ""}`}
```

and not located inside a module (ie `import style from './Game.module.css'`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This accomplished what I needed and still inherited the properties of `.cell`

```
className={`${style.cell} ${cell === Player.Black ? style.black: cell === Player.White ? style.white : ""}`}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following:

```
<div className={`${cell === Player.Black? style.cell + " black" : cell === Player.White ? style.cell + " white" : style.cell}`} key={colIndex}/>
```

or you can make a function and return a CSS string like the one below:

const getCellStyle = () => {
return `cell ${cell === Player.Black ? " black" : cell === Player.White ? " white" : ""}`
}

```
<div className={getCellStyle} key={colIndex}/>
```